# Trying to stop a field callback from firing unexpectedly

Tags: c#

I'm running the following code, and I'm expecting a different outcome.

According to my intent, I would not expect to encounter the firing of my callback function when setting a value.

I would only expect to see my callback fire when checking the value of my field and that field's criteria were met to fire the event.

Could somebody breathe some understanding into this for me?

```
using System.Collections;
public static class CollectionHandler {
    private static List<string> _origFileList = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> origFileList {
        get {
            if (_origFileList.Count < 1) {
                //Fire a Callback Function Call Here
                myTestCallback();
            }
            return _origFileList;
        }
        set {
            _origFileList = value;
        }
    }

    private static void myTestCallback() {
        Console.WriteLine("origFileList - Is now empty");
    }
}
CollectionHandler.origFileList.Add("Value 1");
CollectionHandler.origFileList.Add("Value 2");
CollectionHandler.origFileList.RemoveAt(1);
CollectionHandler.origFileList.RemoveAt(0);
//Output> origFileList - Is now empty
CollectionHandler.origFileList.Add("Test Value #1 - Should not fire the callback !!! But it does");
//Output> origFileList - Is now empty
CollectionHandler.origFileList.Add("Test Value #2 - Should not fire the callback --- And it doesn't");
```

Comment: You are getting the `origFileList` of `CollectionHandler` to add or remove entries to the list. You don't set the list, but the list items.

Comment: You can gain total understanding if you set a breakpoint in the getter and debug your program. Step through and watch the value of `_origFileList`.

Comment: @ckuri Your saying that adding an entry via '.Add' is first 'get'ting the _origFileList, and then adding the entry? This would make sense if it were consistent with my first '.Add("Value 1")', but the callback didn't fire there.

Comment: @RickRiggs Yes, it first needs to get the list it wants to change.

Comment: You might have better luck creating a new class that wraps around an internal list, and provides its own `Add`, and `Remove` methods that proxy to the internal list.  Your new list could even implement `IList<T>`, so that it is almost transparently usable in place of what you are doing now.

Comment: @BradleyUffner, I appreciate this suggestion, as I can then check status in those methods, and fire my "callback" from there. Thank you.

Comment: [You do not need to mark questions as "SOLVED" via editing the title](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/295637), or [posting updates/thanks in posts](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/109959/295637). Simply add your own answer below. Anything additional can be perceived as noise for future visitors. See: [Can I answer my own question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand what's going on you have to modify your code a little bit:

```
void Main()
{
    CollectionHandler.origFileList.Add("Value 1");
    CollectionHandler.origFileList.Add("Value 2");
    CollectionHandler.origFileList.RemoveAt(1);
    CollectionHandler.origFileList.RemoveAt(0);
    //Output> origFileList - Is now empty
    CollectionHandler.origFileList.Add("Test Value #1 - Should not fire the callback !!! But it does");
    //Output> origFileList - Is now empty
    CollectionHandler.origFileList.Add("Test Value #2 - Should not fire the callback --- And it doesn't");
}
public static class CollectionHandler
{
    private static List<string> _origFileList = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> origFileList
    {
        get
        {
            myTestCallback(_origFileList);
            if (_origFileList.Count < 1)
            {
                //Fire a Callback Function Call Here
                myTestCallback(_origFileList.Count());
            }
            return _origFileList;
        }
        set
        {
            _origFileList = value;
        }
    }

    private static void myTestCallback(object s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("========");

    }

    private static void myTestCallback(List<string> s)
    {
        foreach (var str in s)
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        Console.WriteLine("========");
    }
}
```

Now you will be able to see the content of the list every time a getter is called.
Basically when this line is executed:

```
CollectionHandler.origFileList.Add("Test Value #1 - Should not fire the callback !!! But it does");
```

the getter is called prior to the `Add()` method when the `origFileList` is actually empty, that why `_origFileList.Count < 1` condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, the problem is in the moment the property is accessed. This is before the action on it has taken place.
To add an alternate solution, which was a bit too long as a comment: you can wrap whichever list is set inside something like a (System.ComponentModel)`BindingList`. The BindingList exposes events to detect changes made to it. (not if the original list itself is a basic list and it is changed by outside sources though).

Example:

```
public static class CollectionHandler {
    private static BindingList<string> _origFileList;
    public static IList<string> origFileList
    {
        get=> _origFileList;
        set
        {
            if(value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
            if(_origFileList != null)
                _origFileList.ListChanged -= OnListChanged;
            _origFileList = new BindingList<string>(value); 
            _origFileList.ListChanged += OnListChanged;
        }
    }

    static void OnListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(_origFileList.Count== 0)
            myTestCallback();
    }

    static CollectionHandler()
    {
        origFileList = new List<string>();
    }

    private static void myTestCallback() {
        Console.WriteLine("origFileList - Is now empty");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After removing the last item, the count is less than one, so the next time you access CollectionHandler.origFileList, the get function is executed and the condition around the callback is checked.

This is effectively the same code, but will illustrate what @ckuri is referring to:

```
CollectionHandler.origFileList.Add("Value 1");
CollectionHandler.origFileList.Add("Value 2");
CollectionHandler.origFileList.RemoveAt(1);
CollectionHandler.origFileList.RemoveAt(0);

var theList = CollectionHandler.origFileList; // myCallBack will be called  as the "get" method is called here
theList.Add("Test Value #1 - Should not fire the callback !!! But it does"); // call back will not be called here

var theListAgain = CollectionHandler.origFileList;  // the get method is called again, but the count == 1 so the callback is not called
theListAgain.Add("Test Value #2 - Should not fire the callback --- And it doesn't");
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post my implementation regarding this.

I know that there is a lot of improvement to be made on this code (eg. exposing delegates to subscribe to, etc...), but for the purposes of gaining simple control over the adding and removing of items from the list, I simply wrapped it up and defined my own Add / RemoveAt methods (per Bradley Uffner's Comment on my OP).

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        CollectionHandler.origFileList.Add("Value 1");
        CollectionHandler.origFileList.Add("Value 2");
        CollectionHandler.origFileList.RemoveAt(1);
        CollectionHandler.origFileList.RemoveAt(0);
        CollectionHandler.origFileList.Add("Test Value #1");
        CollectionHandler.origFileList.Add("Test Value #2");
        Console.Read();
    }
}

public static class CollectionHandler {
    private static rrList _origFileList = new rrList();
    public static rrList origFileList {
        get {
            return _origFileList;
        }
        set {
            _origFileList = value;
        }
    }
}

public class rrList {
    private List<string> _origFileList = new List<string>();

    private void myTestCallback() {
        Console.WriteLine("List Is now empty");
    }

    private void ListChanged() {
        Console.WriteLine("List Size: " + _origFileList.Count);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int i) {
        _origFileList.RemoveAt(i);
        checkList();
    }

    public void Add(string stringToAdd) {
        _origFileList.Add(stringToAdd);
        checkList();
    }

    private void checkList() {
        if (_origFileList.Count == 0) {
            myTestCallback();
        } else {
            ListChanged();
        }
    }
}
```